# Invoke javascript on the change of a document property via a python script

Tags: spotfire

Usecase - There is a python script which changes the value of an input field property control(say input1). Need to invoke a javascript whenever this document property(input1) changes. Tried using the change event in the javascript but it does not trigger the javascript. The javascript triggers only if we manually set a value and click in the text area to submit the value.

Has anyone found a workaround for this? Using Spotfire version 7.0

Comment: How are you setting the value of the input property control if it is t done by the user?

Comment: The value of the property control is changed via the python script which is triggered manually.

Comment: Ok. So python -> property control -> JavaScript. I'd look to just trigger the JS from the python script

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully done this by adding a space to the html in the text area via the IronPython script.

```
#add a space to trigger JavaScript
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import HtmlTextArea
txt.As[HtmlTextArea]().HtmlContent += " "
```

txt is an input parameter of type Visualization.  Make sure this is the Text Area visualization where your JavaScript is that you wish to trigger.  If you place this at the end of the python script that is updating the property control it should trigger the JavaScript as it re-renders the Text Area visualization. Hope this helps!